# Always have a vertex selected

Tags: java, jung

I am currently using Jung.
I'm trying to prevent selected vertex from clearing when the user click outside of the vertex.

I want it so that there will always be one vertex selected.  Anyway to do this using jung?

I tried using `PickedState<Object> pickedState.addItemListener()` but it doesn't work.

It looks like when I tell it to repick itself when being unpick it will still get unpicked afterword.

Comment: What vertex will remain selected if you have >= 2 vertices selected when you click outside?

Answer (score 0):

This is a small workaround I can think of until I can find a better way

Saved the current selected to a lists

create a new DefaultModalGraphMouse()

override the mouseReleased()

- have it get 'vv.getPickedVertexState().getPicked())'
- If there is a size zero, reactivated the saved selected
- if not then clear the Saved Selected List and add the new ones into it for next time.

Only downside for this is that when there is a mouse pressed it will make all the Vertex unselected until mouse released.